# Jenkins issue with Xcode 6 application: 'Code Sign error: No code signing identities found'

Tags: objective-c, jenkins, xcode6

I'm getting a Jenkins error when building an Xcode project. I know many have had this issue - and I've read and tried hours worth of tips to no avail.

This is the Execute Shell command I'm telling Jenkins to run:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR='/Applications/Xcode 6.app/Contents/Developer/'

cd TM
xcrun xcodebuild clean build
```

Here is the error message in my Jenkins output:

```
=== CLEAN TARGET TM OF PROJECT TM WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
[BEROR]Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/TM/workspace/TM/build/Release-iphoneos/TM.app

Clean.Remove clean build/Release-iphoneos/TM.app
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/TM/workspace/TM/build/Release-iphoneos/TM.app

Clean.Remove clean build/Release-iphoneos/TM.app.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/TM/workspace/TM/build/Release-iphoneos/TM.app.dSYM

Clean.Remove clean build/TM.build/Release-iphoneos/TM.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/TM/workspace/TM/build/TM.build/Release-iphoneos/TM.build

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD TARGET TM OF PROJECT TM WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Tips I've tried with no success:

- I've set my Code Signing in my Build Settings (current, Release = Don't Code Sign; Release > Any iOS SDK = iPhone Developer).
- I've indicated in the Xcode plugin Configuration where my login.keychain file is.
- I've uploaded my .developerprofile to Jenkins and indicated it should be imported before each build.

And more.

Not sure what else I can do. It seems significant that it says `team ID “(null)”` - but I can't find any answers on why that is.

I am running Xcode 6 with a target of iOS 8.0.

Comment: I'm experience this too.  But did it work on xcode 5?  If so maybe try xcode 5.  Or try updating jenkins and other plugins to see if it helps.  If you find the answer please post

Comment: Any luck this issue?

Comment: nope. went with Travis until I feel like grappling with it again

Comment: Same issue here with iOS8.1, have you got any solutions?

Comment: I abandoned using Jenkins, so if someone finds one of these Answers works, let me know

Answer (score 0):

I wish this could be a help.
An example script.
http://blog.octo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/build.txt

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this issue with Jenkins and Xcode 6.4.

Make sure that you have at least one Developer Certificate in your login keychain. Right-click on the certificate and click "Get Info" to show permissions.

Expand the "Trust" list and for the field "When using this certificate", select "Always trust".

Close the window. There should now be a blue "+" sign on the Dev certificate.

Happy Jenkins!